# How to get parameters of calling class

Tags: php, class, object

I have one class that creates an instance of another class.  Is it possible for the second class to retrieve parameters from the calling class.

For example

```
Class_A {
    protected $myArray = array('item 1', 'item2', 'item3')

    public function __construct()
    {
        $nextClass = new ClassB();
        echo $nextClass->countArrayItems();
    }
}

Class_B {
    public function countArrayItems()
    {
        return count(Class_A->myArray);
    }
}

$newClass = new Class_A;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a reference to your `Class_A` instance to your `Class_B` constructor:

```
Class_A {
    public $myArray = array('item 1', 'item2', 'item3')

    public function __construct()
    {
        $nextClass = new Class_B($this);
        echo $nextClass->countArrayItems();
    }
}

Class_B {
    public function __construct($classA_instance) {
        $this->classA_instance = $classA_instance;
    }
    public function countArrayItems()
    {
        return count($this->classA_instance->myArray);
    }
}

$newClass = new Class_A;
```

(as noted by @chris, Class_A->myArray needs to be public)

Comment: I agree this would be the way to go here. This pattern is known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: I would further define an interface and force the class instances to match it. `function __construct(ClassA $classA) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Only if you pass the instance of class A to class B

```
Class_A { 
    protected $myArray = array('item 1', 'item2', 'item3') 

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $nextClass = new ClassB(); 
        echo $nextClass->countArrayItems($this); 
    } 
} 

Class_B { 
    public function countArrayItems($callingClass) 
    { 
        return count($callingClass->myArray); 
    } 
} 


$newClass = new Class_A;
```